# quantum order in a (generalized) thermal steady state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, topological-phase, quantum-statistics

It is known that starting from an initial product state, non-integrable systems will thermalize and eventually local observables can be described by a Gibbs ensemble. It has also been argued that a generalized Gibbs ensemble is what describes the steady state of integrable systems.

The Hamiltonian evolving these states can belong to different phases, either symmetry breaking ones or topological ones. Typically these phases are defined as ground state properties and are detected by either local or non-local order-parameters.

My question is, can we still get the signature of what phase the Hamiltonian belongs to by evaluating these order-parameters in the steady state of these Hamiltonians? In other words, can the Gibbs ensemble or generalized Gibbs ensemble give us information on the phase of the Hamiltonian? If no, where can I find a no-go theorem for this?